# Passing SelectedCells Information to another DataGrid on different page

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, cells, datagridcell

I have tried many things to get around this problem and I cannot seem to find the right answer.

I have a `DataGrid` with 6 Columns, and the user should only be redirected to the other page when they click on any row on **Column 6**.

[image]

So the user can only click on any of the Cells under `To-Do`. When they click on that row I need it to find the `Type` which is in the same row as that cell. **E.G if I clicked the 6 `To-Do`, It should know I have clicked on the row type `Football`.**

I want this then to pass the `Type` that's in the first column to another page so I can bring up all the different `To-Do` items under that `Type`.

This is what I tried:

```
        cSViewEntity selectedView = dgFake.SelectedItem as cSViewEntity;

        AllocateAudits page = new AllocateAudits()
        {
            DataContext = selectedView
        };
        FrameNavigation.Navigate(page);
```

But when I did this it doesn't hit this method:

```
    public void Page_OnNavigatedTo(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        var newDataContext = e.Content;

        _View = (cSViewEntity)newDataContext;

        _Transactions = new List<cAuditTransactionTypeEntity>();

        _Transactions = sp.GetTransactionTypes().ToList();

         string TransactionType = _View.TransactionType;

        int TransactionTypeID = _Transactions.FirstOrDefault(w => w.TransactionType == TransactionType).TransactionTypeId;

        dgAllocate.ItemsSource = sp.GetTransactionsNotEvaluated(TransactionTypeID).ToList();
    }
```

Any help would be very helpful,

Thanks.

**ANSWER TO QUESTION:**

I passed the SelectedItem to the other page, then found the Type on that page and ran a Stored Procedure on that Type.

```
cSViewEntity obj = (cSViewEntity)dgFake.SelectedItem;
     AllocateAudits page = new AllocateAudits(obj)
     {
         DataContext = obj
     };
         FrameNavigation.Navigate(page);
     }
```

And then you pass it to the constructor and then in the start of your method you add this.

```
 private void Rawr(cSViewEntity obj)
 {
      var transactiontype = _obj.TransactionType;

      //Stores the information from newDataContext to the entity with the name of _View.
      _View = (cSViewEntity)obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the last column (column6) I would suggest you create a Datagrid templateCell.

for example :

```
<DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
 <DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="To Do" >
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
     <Button x:Name="MyNavigationButton" Content="{Binding ToDo}" Click="MyClickEvent"/>
    </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

in Code Behind, run the MyClickEvent

```
private void MyClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var myBTNData = ((Button)sender).DataContext;

 //here does follow your code based on the myBTNData
}
```

Hope it gets you started. You also can use other elements (like a hyperlink)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing is I didn't want to add Buttons or a Check box, I just wanted the user to click on the row. Is this possible to find the Type from clicking on the cell or even just clicking on the row?

Comment: You could also try and use a mousedown event, but this will always be a row event.

Comment: Going to update my Question with the answer that I worked out.